# Bug or feature in Rf_initEmbeddedR (R-3.3.3 Linux) gives "Error: C stack usage <large int> is too close to the limit"?

Tags: c++, c, r, linux, multithreading

I believe that some of the logic that sets R_CStackStart in routine Rf_initialize_R of 'R-3.3.3/src/unix/system.c' does not work when Rf_initEmbeddedR is called from a thread other than the main thread.

In my case the value of R_CStackStart was set by the following line of code in a thread other than the main thread:-

R_CStackStart = (uintptr_t) __libc_stack_end;

But setting R_CStackStart to this value caused R to print the messages "Error: C stack usage  <large int> is too close to the limit" followed by a crash at some point before Rf_initEmbeddedR exited.

I was able to get the code to run without error messages or a crash by stepping through it in gdb and setting the value of R_CStackStart back to its default of -1 after the above line of code.

Is this a bug or a feature of the R software in this routine?

Comment: I would call it a bug.